# How is calculated the rate of arrival of humans in the shelter?

Tags: doomsday-clicker

In Doomsday Clicker, the amount of humans in the shelter is the amount of mutants you carry over to the next iteration to reach higher bonus levels.

But sometimes the amount of humans just won't grow, sometimes they get a huge growth spurt, and it seems very awkward.

On other clicker games, the growth rate is very deterministic, is it not the case for this one?

What criteria does the game uses to add more humans to the shelter? How can I increase this rate?